# It says method does not overide any method from its super class, what do i do?

Tags: swift, overriding

It says method does not overide any method from its super class, what do i do? please help

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

Comment: From which class do you inherit?

Comment: thanks it helped but now i have another problem

Comment: for touch: AnyObject in touches {

Comment: it says expected declaration

Comment: @MarkasPovilaika: Just `for touch in touches { ... }`.

Comment: @MartinR is that what you mean for touch in touches {AnyObject}

Comment: @MarkasPovilaika: `for touch in touches { <your code here> }`. If that does not help, ask a new question.